# difference between getLoginStatus and getUser

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-login, facebook-authentication

Consider the following code snippet from developrs.facebook.com

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
```

Next,
consider the following

```
$facebook = new Facebook($config);              

$user = $facebook->getUser();
$userdata = null;
if($user)
{
    try{
        $userdata = $facebook->api('/me');
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        $e->getMessage();
    }
}

$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => $scope);
if(!$userdata)
{                   
    //redirect to login
}
```

My second code is doing everything that the first code promises to do . So why should i use the first method?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, those are two completely different approaches/techniques you are talking about here:

Whereas the first on is part of the JS SDK and therefor *client-side*, the second one using the PHP SDK works *server-side*.

While you can recognize the user server-side as long as a cookie for them is set under your domain, the PHP SDK `getUser` method is not able to recognize a recurring visit by a user once after those cookies are gone.

The JS SDK however is able to make a cross-domain request on the client – so even if no cookies are set any more under your domain, it can call facebook.com and determine the login status of the user.

If you call `getLoginUrl` and automatically redirect the user there if `getUser` did not give a user id, then the effect is basically the same in the end. But this way, the user will notice the redirect to FB and back to your site happening, whereas the JS SDK does all of this “silently” in the background.

And it will prompt the user with the login dialog, if they have not connected to your app before – the JS SDK `FB.getLoginStatus` however gives you 'not_authorized' – that’s helpful in cases where you just want to now if you *have* a user that has connected to your app before, but don’t want to bother other users with forcing a login dialog on them. For the PHP SDK, they recently introduced a method [getLoginStatusUrl](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginStatusUrl/), which does the same – but it still needs redirects.

Comment: by cookies set under your domain,u r referring to the cookies saved on the client machine,right??dumb question,but could not help but ask. I deleted the cookies on a system that was used by to authorize an app,however on re-login,i wasn't asked for permissions.

Comment: Yes of course, cookies stored on the client machine, so in the browser. But if you go through the server-side login flow again, it will just be a redirect to Facebook and then straight back – because you have already connected to the app and given it permissions, so there’s no reason to bring up the dialog asking for them again. (The fact that you have given permission to an app is of course not stored in client-side cookies; this info is stored by Facebook on their servers.)